# Oracle apex - it is possible to change region width on button click?

Tags: oracle-apex

i have 2 regions next to each other.

[image: appbuilder screen]

[image: apex screen]

*the one on the left:*

*-column: automatic*

*-column span: 3*

*the one on the right:*

*-column: automatic*

*-column span: automatic*

I'd like to hide one of regions (left one) and extend right region on full widht.
I tried use set new width with js on button click, but it doesn't work.
Is there a solution?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option:

- I created two regions, `LEFT` and `RIGHT`

  - `LEFT`:

    - column: automatic / column span: 3
    - server-side condition: function that returns boolean: `RETURN NVL(:P16_HLR, 1) = 1;`
  - `RIGHT`: column and column span: automatic
- in `RIGHT` region, I created a hidden item named `P16_HLR` with `1` as default value
- in `RIGHT` region, I also created a `P16_TOGGLE_LEFT` button which submits the page and runs the process:

  ```
  :P16_HLR := CASE WHEN NVL(:P16_HLR, 1) = 0 THEN 1
                   WHEN NVL(:P16_HLR, 1) = 1 THEN 0
              END;
  ```

---

That's it; run the page. Initially, both regions are visible and take as many columns as designed. By pressing the button, `LEFT` region is *hidden*, while `RIGHT` region takes whole screen width. Press it again, `LEFT` region is back and `RIGHT` takes the rest of the screen.

[image]